# javascript infovis toolkit: individal level distance for each level

Tags: javascript, jstree, toolkit, infovis, space-tree

how do i set individual levelDistance for each level in spacetree 
when i set node.data.$width and label.style.width tree drawn with no equal edge

How to set levelDistance for each node level in the spacetree. For instance, I want to change the 'levelDistance' for node level 3. Thank you

```
function init(){
//init data

  json = {
    id: "node0",
    name: "zvet",
    data: {},
    children: [{
        id: "node0rrrrrr1",
        name: "1.3",
        data: {$orn:'left'},
        children: [{
             id: "fvwerr1",
             name: "w33",
             data: {$orn:'left'},
        }]

    },
    {
        id: "node02",
        name: "qwe",
        data: {$orn:'left'}

    } ,{
        id: "node03",
        name: "bnm",
        data: {$orn:'left'}

    } ,{
        id: "node04",
        name: "1.3",
        data: {$orn:"right",kk:"kk"}

    },



    {
        id: "vwer",
        name: "vfsewrg",
        data: {$orn:"right",kk:"kk"}

    },
    {
        id: "vweq33e",
        name: "vvvserser",
        data: {$orn:"right",kk:"kk"},
        children: [{
             id: "r345345",
             name: "w33",
             data: {$orn:'right'}
        },
        {
             id: "u786786",
             name: "w33",
             data: {$orn:'right'}
        },
        {
             id: "p809456",
             name: "w33",
             data: {$orn:'right'},
             children: [{
                 id: "weqr232344",
                 name: "w33",
                data: {$orn:'right',kk:"kk"},
                 children: [{
                 id: "weqoooooppp",
                 name: "w33",
                data: {$orn:'right'}
             }]
             }]


        }
        ]

    }

     ]      
};
//end
//init Spacetree
//Create a new ST instance
st = new $jit.ST({
    //id of viz container element
    injectInto: 'infovis',
    Canvas:{
    type: '2D'}  ,
    background:true,
    //set duration for the animation
    duration: 800,
    //set animation transition type
    transition: $jit.Trans.Quart.easeInOut,
    //set distance between node and its children
   levelDistance: 100,
    levelsToShow:5,          
    multitree: true,
    //enable panning
    Navigation: {
      enable:true,
      panning:true
    },
    //set node and edge styles
    //set overridable=true for styling individual
    //nodes or edges
    Node: {
        height: 20,
        width: 150,
        type: 'rectangle',
        color:'transparent',            
        overridable: true,
        autoWidth:false ,
        CanvasStyles: {  
        fillStyle: 'transparent'                     
        }
    },              
     Edge: {  
     type: 'bezier',  
    overridable: true  
}, 


    onBeforeCompute: function(node){
        Log.write("loading " + node.name);
    },

    onAfterCompute: function(){
        Log.write("done");
    },

    //This method is called on DOM label creation.
    //Use this method to add event handlers and styles to
    //your node.
    onCreateLabel: function(label, node){
        label.id = node.id;            
        label.innerHTML = node.name;
        label.innerHTML='<div  style="position:relative;">'+node.name+'</div>';

        label.onclick = function(){
            if(normal.checked) {
                st.onClick(node.id);
                //st.setRoot(node.id, 'animate'); 
                st.selectedNodeId=node.id;
                $("#"+node.id+" div").animate({"bottom":"+=10px"},"slow");
             //st.addNodeInPath("1234");                                 

            } else {
            st.setRoot(node.id, 'animate');
            }
        };
        //set label styles
         var style = label.style;  
    style.width = 150 + 'px';  
    style.height = 17 + 'px';              
    style.cursor = 'pointer';  
    style.color = '#fff';  
    style.backgroundColor = '#6257DD';  
    style.borderradius='14px';
    style.boxshadow='0 0 16px #FFFFFF';
    style.fontSize = '0.8em';  
    style.textAlign= 'center';         
    style.paddingTop = '3px';  
        if(node.data.kk=="kk")
        {
            style.width = 60+ 'px';
        } 

    },
    onPlaceLabel: function(label, node) {  

}  ,

    //This method is called right before plotting
    //a node. It's useful for changing an individual node
    //style properties before plotting it.
    //The data properties prefixed with a dollar
    //sign will override the global node style properties.
    onBeforePlotNode: function(node){
            if(node.data.kk=="kk")
        {
            node.data.$width = 60;  
        } 
        //add some color to the nodes in the path between the
        //root node and the selected node.
        if (node.selected) {
            node.data.$color = "#000000";

            $("#"+node.id).css("background-color","red");
        }
        else {
            delete node.data.$color;

            $("#"+node.id).css("background-color","#6257DD");
            //if the node belongs to the last plotted level
            if(!node.anySubnode("exist")) {
                //count children number
                var count = 0;
                node.eachSubnode(function(n) { count++; });
                //assign a node color based on
                //how many children it has
                node.data.$color = ['#aaa', '#baa', '#caa', '#daa', '#eaa', '#faa'][count];                    
            }
        }
    },

    //This method is called right before plotting
    //an edge. It's useful for changing an individual edge
    //style properties before plotting it.
    //Edge data proprties prefixed with a dollar sign will
    //override the Edge global style properties.
    onBeforePlotLine: function(adj){

        if (adj.nodeFrom.selected && adj.nodeTo.selected) {
            adj.data.$color = "#eed";
            adj.data.$lineWidth = 3;
        }
        else {
            delete adj.data.$color;
            delete adj.data.$lineWidth;
        }
    }
});
//load json data

//end
//Add event handlers to switch spacetree orientation.
var top = $jit.id('r-top'), 
    left = $jit.id('r-left'), 
    bottom = $jit.id('r-bottom'), 
    right = $jit.id('r-right'),
    normal = $jit.id('s-normal');


function changeHandler() {
    if(this.checked) {
        top.disabled = bottom.disabled = right.disabled = left.disabled = true;
        st.switchPosition(this.value, "animate", {
            onComplete: function(){
                top.disabled = bottom.disabled = right.disabled = left.disabled = false;
            }
        });
    }
};

st.loadJSON(json);
//compute node positions and layout
st.compute();
//optional: make a translation of the tree
st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");
//emulate a click on the root node.
st.onClick(st.root);
st.select(st.root);
top.onchange = left.onchange = bottom.onchange = right.onchange = changeHandler;
//end
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have different distances for different levels.

What you can do is to change the node.data.$size of the level, so it displays smaller or bigger than the other leaves.

Think the distance as an allocated space for the node to be placed in. If you create a node with a size smaller than the distance, you will get a gap, which can be seeing as a "border" (just visually) at the external part of it.